# Deserialize<List<>>(jsonReader) with KeyAttributeValues

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON file with the following:
[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xgfF.png)

How would I go about Deserializing this? I am receiving an error requesting to use an Array.

Heres my main code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BpZp.png)

Here is my Colors class:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzX4L.png)

If I remove everything in the JSON except the color, category, type and code fields then I can use the Deserialize>(JsonReader) call however I have keyattributevalues here with tte Code class. Any suggestions on how to include this?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, you can copy them into your question, some people can't see the sites that are linked (even imgur).

Comment: Plus we can't copy/paste from them....

Comment: Please post the code inline, and not in the form of screenshots on an external server, from which they will probably disappear sooner or later.

Comment: JSON is an object containing a property "colors" which contains an array of colours. You're trying to deserialize an object to an array, of course it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to deserialize as a simple `List<Color>` when your JSON is actually *an object that has a **property** named `colors`* which is not the same...

Either your JSON needs to look like this:

```
[
    {
        "color":"white",
        "category":"etc",
        "code":{
            "rgba":"xxx",
            ....
        }
    },
    {
        "color":"green",
        "category":"etc",
        ...
    }
]
```

OR you need another higher-level class (is that what `MyColors` is meant to do?):

```
public class ColorsCollection
{
    public IEnumerable<Color> Colors { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
var colorCollection = Serializer.Deserialize<ColorsCollection>(jsonReader);
```